# How to change the camera postion in which the player sees through in my Add-on?(Bedrock Edition)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-behavior-packs

How do **I** make it so the **camera is attached** to the ***Warden's*** head in my ***Behavior Pack***?

This is **SO** annoying and it really messes up my Addon.
Code:

Behavior Pack:

```
{
  "format_version": "1.16.0",
  "minecraft:entity": {
    "description": {
      "identifier": "minecraft:player","minecraft:warden",
      "is_spawnable": true,
      "is_summonable": true,
      "is_experimental": false
    },
    "component_groups": {
      "emerging": {
        "minecraft:behavior.emerge": {
          "duration": 7.0,
          "on_done": {
            "event": "minecraft:emerged",
            "target": "self"
          }
        }
      },
      "pushable": {
        "minecraft:pushable": {
          "is_pushable": true,
          "is_pushable_by_piston": true
        }
      }
    },
    "components": {
      "minecraft:hurt_on_condition": {
        "damage_conditions": [
          {
            "filters": { "test": "in_lava", "subject": "self", "operator": "==", "value": true },
            "cause": "lava",
            "damage_per_tick": 4
          }
        ]
      },
      "minecraft:attack": {
        "damage": 100
      },
      "minecraft:collision_box": {
        "width": 10,
        "height": 15,
      },
      "minecraft:exhaustion_values": {
        "heal": 6,
        "jump": 0.05,
        "sprint_jump": 0.2,
        "mine": 0.005,
        "attack": 10,
        "damage": 0.1,
        "walk": 0.0,
        "sprint": 0.1,
        "swim": 0.01
      },
      "minecraft:attack": {
        "damage": 1000
      },
        "minecraft:movement_sound_distance_offset": {
        "value": 0.55
      },
      "minecraft:experience_reward": {
        "on_bred": "Math.Random(1,7)",
        "on_death": "query.last_hit_by_player ? 5 : 0"
      },
      "minecraft:vibration_listener": {},
      "minecraft:vibration_damper": {},
      "minecraft:suspect_tracking": {},
      "minecraft:anger_level": {
        "max_anger": 150,
        "angry_threshold": 80,
        "remove_targets_below_angry_threshold": true,
        "angry_boost": 20,
        "anger_decrement_interval": 1.0,
        "default_annoyingness": 35,
        "default_projectile_annoyingness":  10,
        "on_increase_sounds": [
          { "sound": "listening_angry", "condition" : "query.anger_level(this) >= 40" },
          { "sound": "listening", "condition" : "query.anger_level(this) >= 0" }
        ],
        "nuisance_filter": {
          "all_of": [
            { "test": "is_family", "subject": "other", "operator": "not", "value": "warden" },
            { "test": "is_family", "subject": "other", "operator": "not", "value": "inanimate" }
          ]
        }
      },
      "minecraft:is_hidden_when_invisible": {
      },
      "minecraft:type_family": {
        "family": [
          "warden",
          "monster",
          "mob"
        ]
      },
      "minecraft:breathable": {
        "total_supply": 15,
        "suffocate_time": 0
      },
      "minecraft:navigation.walk": {
        "can_path_over_water": true,
        "can_path_over_lava": true,
        "avoid_damage_blocks": true
      },
      "minecraft:preferred_path": {
        "max_fall_blocks": 20
      },
      "minecraft:ambient_sound_interval": {
        "value": 2.0,
        "range": 4.0,
        "event_name": "ambient",
        "event_names": [
          {
            "event_name" : "angry",
            "condition" : "query.anger_level(this) >= 80"
          },
          {
            "event_name" : "agitated",
            "condition" : "query.anger_level(this) >= 40"
          }
        ]
      },
      "minecraft:heartbeat": {
        "interval": "2.0 - math.clamp(query.anger_level / 80 * 1.5, 0, 1.5)"
      },
      "minecraft:movement.basic": {},
      "minecraft:jump.static": {},
      "minecraft:can_climb": {},
      "minecraft:collision_box": {
        "width": 0.9,
        "height": 2.9
      },
      "minecraft:health": {
        "value": 500,
        "max": 500
      },
      "minecraft:movement": {
        "value": 0.3
      },
      "minecraft:knockback_resistance": {
        "value": 1.0
      },
      "minecraft:behavior.float": {
        "priority": 0
      },
      "minecraft:behavior.dig": {
        "priority": 1,
        "duration": 5.5,
        "idle_time": 60.0,
        "vibration_is_disturbance": true,
        "suspicion_is_disturbance": true,
        "digs_in_daylight": false,
        "on_start": {
          "event": "on_digging_event",
          "target": "self"
        }
      },
      "minecraft:behavior.roar": {
        "priority": 2,
        "duration": 4.2
      },
      "minecraft:behavior.sonic_boom": {
        "priority": 3,
        "duration": 3.0,
        "speed_multiplier": 1.2,
        "attack_damage": 10,
        "attack_range_horizontal": 15,
        "attack_range_vertical": 20,
        "attack_cooldown": 2,
        "knockback_vertical_strength": 0.5,
        "knockback_horizontal_strength": 2.5,
        "knockback_height_cap": 0.5,
        "duration_until_attack_sound": 1.7,
        "charge_sound": "sonic_charge",
        "attack_sound": "sonic_boom"
      },
      "minecraft:behavior.melee_attack": {
        "priority": 4,
        "speed_multiplier": 1.2,
        "melee_fov": 360
      },
      "minecraft:behavior.investigate_suspicious_location": {
        "priority": 5,
        "speed_multiplier": 0.7
      },
      "minecraft:behavior.sniff": {
        "priority": 6,
        "duration": 4.16,
        "sniffing_radius": 24.0,
        "suspicion_radius_horizontal" : 6.0,
        "suspicion_radius_vertical": 20.0,
        "cooldown_range": [ 5.0, 10.0 ]
      },
      "minecraft:behavior.random_stroll": {
        "priority": 9,
        "speed_multiplier": 0.5
      },
      "minecraft:behavior.random_look_around": {
        "priority": 11
      },
      "minecraft:physics": {},
      "minecraft:mob_effect": {
        "effect_range": 20,
        "effect_time": 13,
        "mob_effect": "darkness",
        "cooldown_time": 6,
        "entity_filter": {
          "all_of": [
            { "test": "is_family", "subject": "other", "value": "player" },
            { "operator": "not", "test": "has_ability", "subject" : "other", "value" : "invulnerable" }
          ]
        }
      },
      "minecraft:follow_range": 30,
      "minecraft:fire_immune": {},
      "minecraft:nameable": {},
      "minecraft:loot": {
        "table": "loot_tables/entities/warden.json"
      }
    },
    "events": {
      "minecraft:spawn_emerging": {
        "add": {
          "component_groups": [
            "emerging"
          ]
        }
      },
      "minecraft:emerged": {
        "add": {
          "component_groups": [
            "pushable"
          ]
        },
        "remove": {
          "component_groups": [
            "emerging"
          ]
        }
      },
      "minecraft:entity_spawned": {
        "add": {
          "component_groups": [
            "pushable"
          ]
        }
      },
      "on_digging_event": {
        "remove": {
          "component_groups": [
            "pushable"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Resource Pack:

```
{ 
  "format_version": "1.10.0",
  "minecraft:client_entity": {
    "description": {
      "identifier": "minecraft:player",
      "materials": {
        "default": "warden",
        "bioluminescent_layer": "warden_bioluminescent_layer"
      },
      "textures": {
        "default": "textures/entity/steve.png",
        "bioluminescent_layer": "textures/entity/1.png",
        "spots_1": "textures/entity/5.png",
        "spots_2": "textures/entity/4.png",
        "tendrils": "textures/entity/6.png",
        "heart": "textures/entity/2.png"
      },
      "geometry": { "default": "geometry.warden" },
      "scripts": {
        "pre_animation": [
          "variable.animation_speed = Math.min(0.5, 3.0 * query.modified_move_speed);",
          "variable.anim_pos_mod = 49.388962;",
          "variable.bob = query.life_time * 20;",
          "variable.modified_bob = variable.bob * 0.1 * 57.2958;",
          "variable.modified_bob_sin = math.sin(variable.modified_bob);",
          "variable.modified_bob_cos = math.cos(variable.modified_bob);",
          "variable.pi = 180;",
          "variable.halfpi = variable.pi / 2.0;",
          "variable.tendril_animation_length = 0.5;",
          "variable.head_x_rot = (68.7549 * math.cos(query.modified_distance_moved * variable.anim_pos_mod + variable.halfpi) * math.min(0.35, variable.animation_speed)) + (math.sin(variable.bob * 5.72958) * 0.06);",
          "variable.head_z_rot = (17.1887 * math.sin(query.modified_distance_moved * variable.anim_pos_mod) * variable.animation_speed) + (Math.cos(variable.bob * 5.72958) * 0.06);",
          "variable.body_x_rot = (57.2958 * math.cos(query.modified_distance_moved * variable.anim_pos_mod) * math.min(0.35, variable.animation_speed)) + (math.cos(variable.bob * 5.72958) * 0.025);",
          "variable.body_z_rot = (5.72958 * math.sin(query.modified_distance_moved * variable.anim_pos_mod) * variable.animation_speed) + (math.sin(variable.bob * 5.72958) * 0.025);",
          "variable.left_leg_x_rot = 57.2958 * math.cos(query.modified_distance_moved * variable.anim_pos_mod) * variable.animation_speed;",
          "variable.right_leg_x_rot = 57.2958 * math.cos(query.modified_distance_moved * variable.anim_pos_mod + variable.pi) * variable.animation_speed;",
          "variable.left_arm_x_rot = -(45.8366 * math.cos(query.modified_distance_moved * variable.anim_pos_mod) * variable.animation_speed);",
          "variable.right_arm_x_rot = -(45.8366 * math.sin(query.modified_distance_moved * variable.anim_pos_mod) * variable.animation_speed);",
          "variable.vibration_phase = query.time_since_last_vibration_detection;",
          "variable.tendril_animation = variable.vibration_phase  0.0" },
          "sonic_boom_controller"
        ]
      },
      "animations": {
        "emerge": "animation.warden.emerge",
        "sniff": "animation.warden.sniff",
        "sniff_controller": "controller.animation.warden.sniff",
        "dig": "animation.warden.dig",
        "roar": "animation.warden.roar",
        "roar_controller": "controller.animation.warden.roar",
        "shiver": "animation.warden.shiver",
        "shiver_controller": "controller.animation.warden.shiver",
        "base_pose": "animation.humanoid.base_pose.v1.0",
        "look_at_target": "animation.warden.look_at_target.default",
        "move": "animation.warden.move",
        "melee_attack": "animation.warden.attack",
        "melee_attack_controller": "controller.animation.warden.melee_attacking",
        "bob": "animation.warden.bob",
        "swimming": "animation.humanoid.swimming.v1.0",
        "sonic_boom": "animation.warden.sonic_boom",
        "sonic_boom_controller": "controller.animation.warden.sonic_boom"
      },
      "render_controllers": [
        "controller.render.warden",
        "controller.render.warden_bioluminescent_layer",
        "controller.render.warden_spots_1",
        "controller.render.warden_spots_2",
        "controller.render.warden_tendrils",
        "controller.render.warden_heart"
       ],
      "enable_attachables": true,
      "spawn_egg": {
        "base_color": "#0F4649",
        "overlay_color": "#39D6E0"
      },
      "sound_effects": {
        "emerge": "mob.warden.emerge",
        "sniff": "mob.warden.sniff",
        "dig": "mob.warden.dig",
        "roar": "mob.warden.roar",
        "clicking": "mob.warden.clicking"
      },
      "particle_effects": {
        "digging": "minecraft:warden_dig"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you copy/paste these things from another site, or did you manually add the HTML code? In any case, Stack Exchange uses MarkDown. You can make use of the editor functions as you type either question or answer.

Comment: I can look into this later, but I believe [what you're after](https://github.com/Mojang/bedrock-samples/blob/main/resource_pack/models/entity/warden.geo.json) is the `visible_bounds_offset` in the geometry for the warden which by default has a value of `2.25` on the y-axis.